# Clickable tiles with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-grid

I want to create clickable tiles for a content area. To realize this I wanted to use CSS Grid and make the individual areas clickable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style class="cp-pen-styles">
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand that I could put a link in the individual cells, but maybe it is possible to click the single cell as a whole ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JS solution that uses no anchors:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

  Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
    box.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert(this.classList[1]);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
/*   padding: 20px; */
  font-size: 150%;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Now you can use `display: flex` to each individual box to arrange it's inner content.

Comment: That looks great. Thanks a lot for this. I think that's exactly what I've been looking for. I have to confess that I'm not as fit as CSS. How can I use the `display:flex` now on each box?

Comment: Glad it helped. It really depends on what you want to achieve. This is a [really good guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)  and what you can do with it. Don't forget to accept a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to make the cells respond onclick. Alternatively, you can use the `a` tag behave as a grid, by adding `display:block` to your .box style class and provide any other css attributes needed.

The caveat is that you won't be able to nest other elements inside your `a` tags.

```
.box {
  display:block;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="box a" href="some_link">A</a>
  <a class="box b" href="some_link">B</a>
  <a class="box c" href="some_link">C</a>
  <a class="box d" href="some_link">D</a>
  <a class="box e" href="some_link">E</a>
  <a class="box f" href="some_link">F</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. With `diplay:block` I can now select the tiles. However, I would like to have content in the respective tiles. Usually it is a picture and a text (no link). Where I also see a problem is that the tiles resize (it is still a CSS grid) when an image or text is inserted that is slightly larger. A grid that would not change its size and position would be good.

Comment: Adding `overflow:hidden` should prevent your tiles from resizing based on contents, so long as the block tiles also have defined dimensions (width, height). However, you may end up with a situation where tile contents are clipped by the hidden overflow. Since tiles have mixed html, best way is to set them as `<div>` elements and use javascript to provide the link functionality.